# Maven Password Encryption Not Working For Sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube

We've been using SonarQube to generate issues reports and after upgrading to SonarQube 5.2 we can't run in preview mode without specifying passwords in plain text, either on the command line or in maven's settings.xml file. We are using the LDAP plugin for authentication. Previously we had used

```
mvn --encrypt-password
```

to encrypt our password without problems.  Users with administration access can encrypt passwords via sonar's encryption, but regular users cannot.

Trying to run preview analysis results in:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project *-parent: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. Fail to download [https://sonar...com/batch/global]. Response code: 401 -> [Help 1]
```

With the password specified in plain text the analysis runs fine.

Versions:
SonarQube 5.2
sonar-maven-plugin 2.7.1
sonar LDAP plugin 1.5

**Update:** this happens for 2 users, 1 with administration access, and another user without administration access can run the analysis fine.